# Realtime Matchmaking Learning Path

Tags: android, ios, node.js, socket.io, matchmaking

I want to implement a real-time multiplayer game, like a word game in my mobile app. I'm sorry if the question is too broad, but I want to set a learning path to myself to achieve my goal.

The idea roughly goes like:

- userA clicks Play Now button and gets directed into a pool
- Every 10 seconds, the pool gets analysed according to data of users (rating, etc) and 5 user to each room with 5x close-rating users in the same rooms.

First of all, I want to ask if this approach is correct?

Secondly, during the game-play, after getting assigned to the rooms, I want:

- User1 selected randomly between 5 users.
- Game starts..
- For the round to finish:

  - User1 has 60 seconds to complete or,
  - All other 4 users click 'success' or 'fail' button.

During rounds, users should be able to real-time chat.

---

To achieve this scenario, what kind of learning path should I set to myself?

Is Node.js, Socket.io and Redis good for achieving what I want to achieve? What do you suggest me as a learning path?

Lastly, I did reading and I came across Google Play Games allow this matchmaking, but requires users to login with Google+ accounts, however I am doing my login with OAuth2, and I don't want to change that. I want to achieve this on my own instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node.js` and `socket.io` will work just fine, I suggest you learn concept of `rooms` in `socket.io` for players to be in the game round. I don't see real need to use `redis`, it is key-value storage, but `mondodb` (or any kind of *sql db) could be useful for some data to be stored, like scores, leaderboards, etc.

Comment: Redis would be ideal I think, because a) Usage of lists for leaderboard etc. , see https://redislabs.com/blog/the-top-3-game-changing-redis-use-cases#.VjsO_bd0-Uk b) When you want to scale your app to multiple nodes later, there's already a plugin to socket.io for that. http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/